# superset 0.37 fail send email

Tags: apache-superset

When I use superset 0.37. I click "Manage"  then  select "Dashboard Emails" to new a Schedule Email.Reports  for Dashboards.
I select Send Test Email.

But I cannot  receive any email.

I already  vi config.py  and modify   SMTP  and  is right.
I could not see Error  in the log.
what should I do next?

Comment: i solution it.  SCHEDULE_EMAIL_DEBUG_MODE = False

Comment: I am still trying to solve . There is no error related to this in docker logs , docker can connect to external relay mail server via port 25, tested by telnet, but still no mail

Answer (score -1):

Try adjust the config in superset_config.py

```
ALERT_REPORTS_NOTIFICATION_DRY_RUN = False
```